# Difficulty importing CSV into MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a CSV file that I'm trying to import into MySQL but one of the columns is being split into several columns.

Here is a sample of the CSV:

```
Code,SpecificIssue,Issues_Id
"MEDICARE/MEDICAID","State Medicaid waivers",0
"EDUCATION","Distance Education, Accreditation, and Issues Affecting Access to Title IV Loans in Higher education Act reauthorization; issues affecting veterans access to education benefits.",1
"LAW ENFORCEMENT/CRIME/CRIMINAL JUSTICE","Issues related to law enforcement funding; S. 3182.",2
"TRANSPORTATION","Issues related to transportation improvements funding.  S. 3261.",2
"HEALTH ISSUES","Issues related to funding for health care outreach, S. 3230.",2
```

The first record is being split between "Distance Education" and "Accreditation", and the last record is being split between "outreach" and "S.".

I'm using the instructions provided at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html as a reference. The SQL import query is like so:

```
load data local infile '/path/to/csv/example.csv' 
into table lobby 
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n';
```

It seems to me that the enclosed by quotes instruction is being ignored, but I have no idea why or how to get around it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` since you do not have quotes on all values.

Without this you are going to get unexpected behavior.

Here is commentary from manual around CSV import:

> LOAD DATA INFILE can be used to read files obtained from external sources. For example, many programs can export data in comma-separated values (CSV) format, such that lines have fields separated by commas and enclosed within double quotation marks, with an initial line of column names. If the lines in such a file are terminated by carriage return/newline pairs, the statement shown here illustrates the field- and line-handling options you would use to load the file:
>
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
>     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
>     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
>     IGNORE 1 LINES;
>
> If the input values are not necessarily enclosed within quotation marks, use OPTIONALLY before the ENCLOSED BY keywords.

Note the last line.

Comment: I tried: load data infile '/issue_d.csv' into table issue fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\r\n' ignore 1 lines; and got the same result. :/ I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your third column has number 0 without '"' enclosed. You may put '"' around them and try again.